# Hydrometer correction equation

Tags: specific-gravity, hydrometer

Can you identify the constants in your hydrometer correction equation?  I know that 2.6X10-6 is the coefficient of thermal expansion for the hydrometer glass; what are the others (not related to converting F to C)?

Comment: Hi can you please add the particular equation you're using?

Answer (score 1):

While I use Beer Smith (or any number of online calculators). I found this article that may be of use to you.

http://hbd.org/brewery/library/HydromCorr0992.html